# How to pass arguments through multiple methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I have some Python code that works but my approach is very tedious. The basic structure is that I have a class that manipulates data through multiple methods and returns the manipulated data. The code structure looks like:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = 0
        
    def __AllCalculation(self,arg1=1,arg2=2):
        self.__Calc1(arg1)
        self.__Calc2(arg2)
        
    def __Calc1(self,arg1):
        self.__data+arg1
    
    def __Calc2(self,arg2):
        self.__data+arg2
        
    def GetResults(self,arg1=1,arg2=2):
        self.__AllCalculation(arg1,arg2)
        return self.__data
```

and the user should only call `GetResults()`. It there a more pythonic approach to cascading the arguments through the functions? This approach works but difficult to maintain as a single change requires multiple rewrites. Ideally if it is possible for `GetResults()` to inherit the arguments from `__AllCalculations()` including the default values.

Comment: do you have multiple types of calculation that need to be done in different circumstances? E.g. you have `calc1, calc2, calc3` and you might need `getresults1` which calls 1 and 2 and `getresults2` which calls 2 and 3

Comment: On a separate thought, it may not be necessary to separate out `getresults` from `__allcalculation`.

Comment: @jrmylow Yes there is potential that I would have different `getresults` that would skip some of the calculations. I know that just removing `getresults` and using `__AllCalculation` directly would solve the issue, but the question still stands; is it possible to propagate the arguments?

Comment: If you are disciplined enough, using `**kwargs` might do the trick

Comment: @jrmylow could you provide an example of how to propagate and keep track of it? I can't get my head around how `GetResults(**kwargs)` are gonna show what the default values in `__AllCalculations` are and convey that information when using the function.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you're asking for is a way for the top function (GetResults) to know what arguments it needs to pass down the chain. Using the current method of building functions, you make sure that each function's signature contains all the variables it's passing on. Like you mentioned, this is tedious to maintain.

Using `**kwargs`, you can get a method to pull out the keyword arguments that it needs to function and drop the rest. It puts the responsibility on the functions/methods at the end of the chain to decide what they need out of `**kwargs`.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = 0
        
    def __AllCalculation(self, **kwargs):
        self.__Calc1(**kwargs)
        self.__Calc2(**kwargs)
        
    def __Calc1(self, arg1, **kwargs):
        self.__data += arg1

    def __Calc2(self, arg2, **kwargs):
        self.__data += arg2
        
    def GetResults(self, **kwargs):
        self.__AllCalculation(**kwargs)
        return self.__data

A = ExampleClass()

print(A.GetResults(arg2 = 3, arg1 = 5, arg3 = 1000))    # Prints 8 = 0 + 5 + 3
```

The question then becomes, how do I know what arguments I need to pass in at the start? If you call the function without supplying the required argument, you will raise `TypeError`, specifying exactly which keyword argument you need to pass through. (Admittedly you may need to call it a few times to catch everything, but at least you only need to change it in one place)